# Using grok to match custom style email address

Tags: regex, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I just set up an ELK stack for my apache logs. It's working great. Now I want to add maillogs to the mix, and I'm having trouble parsing the logs with grok.

I'm using this site to debug:
https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Here is an example maillog (sendmail) entry:

```
Apr 24 19:38:51 ip-10-0-1-204 sendmail[9489]: w3OJco1s009487: to=<username@domain.us>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=smtp, pri=120318, relay=webmx.bglen.net. [10.0.3.231], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as E2DEF60724), w3OJco1s009487: to=<username@domain.us>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=smtp, pri=120318, relay=webmx.[redacted].net. [10.0.3.231], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as E2DEF60724)
```

From the text above, I want to pull out the text `to=<username@domain.us>`.

So far I have this for a grok pattern:

```
(?<mail_sent_to>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-‌​9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*)
```

It gives me the result `username@domain.us>` which is nice, but I want it to have the `to=` on the front as well. And I only want this grok filter to match email addresses which have `to=` in front of them.

I tried this, but it gives me "no matches" as a result:

```
(?<mail_sent_to>"to="[a-zA-Z0-9_.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-‌​9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*)
```

Comment: Try [`\bto=<(?<mail_sent_to>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})*)>`](https://regex101.com/r/a96ahh/1)

Comment: Or, if you need to get the whole `to=<...>`, use [`\b(?<mail_sent_to>to=<[a-zA-Z0-9_.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/a96ahh/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The second one worked! It gives me the whole address with "to=<...>" thank you! Please write as answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?<mail_sent_to>to=<[a-zA-Z0-9_.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})*>)
```

or, since `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` matches the same chars as `\w`:

```
\b(?<mail_sent_to>to=<[\w.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})*>)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a96ahh/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<mail_sent_to>` - "mail_sent_to" group:

  - `to=<` - a literal string `to=<`
  - `[\w.+=:-]+` - 1+ word, `.`, `+`, `=`, `:` or `-` chars
  - `@` - a `@` char
  - `[0-9A-Za-z]` - an alphanumeric char
  - `[0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}` - 0 to 62 letters, digits or `-`
  - `(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})*` - 0+ sequences of

    - `\.` - a dot
    - `[0-9A-Za-z]` - an alphanumeric char
    - `[0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}` - 0 to 62 letters, digits or `-`
  - `>` - a `>` char
- `)` - end of the group.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori I supposed that OP already tried `%{EMAILADDRESS}` and it did not work for them.

Answer (score 2):

This is much simple, it create a custom pattern to match `to=<` and `>`, and [pre-defined EMAILADDRESS](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) to match email address.

```
\b(?<mail_sent_to>to=<%{EMAILADDRESS}>)
```

This will output,

```
{
  "mail_sent_to": [
    [
      "to=<username@domain.us>"
    ]
  ],
  "EMAILADDRESS": [
    [
      "username@domain.us"
    ]
  ],
  "EMAILLOCALPART": [
    [
      "username"
    ]
  ],
  "HOSTNAME": [
    [
      "domain.us"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:**

Patterns for email are,

```
EMAILLOCALPART [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.+-=:]+
EMAILADDRESS %{EMAILLOCALPART}@%{HOSTNAME}
```